# Getting "AttributeError: 'CfnUserPool' object has no attribute 'user_pool_id' " error

Tags: python, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, aws-userpools

I am trying to create "**CfnUserPoolClient**" object using AWS doc -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_cognito/CfnUserPoolClient.html

I have created "**CfnUserPool**" object like this -

```
_cognito_user_pool = _cognito.CfnUserPool(stack, id="pool-id", user_pool_name="user-auth-pool")
```

To create "**CfnUserPoolClient**" object I need ID of "**CfnUserPool**" object.
I am using below code to create "**CfnUserPoolClient**" object-

```
_user_pool_id = _cognito_user_pool.user_pool_id
_cognito_userpool_clients = _cognito.CfnUserPoolClient(stack, id="client-id", user_pool_id=_user_pool_id, client_name="client-name")
```

I am getting below error for this code -

```
AttributeError: 'CfnUserPool' object has no attribute 'user_pool_id'.
```

I think there is no attribute "user_pool_id" for "CfnUserPool" object. 
I have tried "id" to get user pool id like this -

```
_user_pool_id = _cognito_user_pool.id
```

But still I am getting same error and this time it is for "id".

So how can I get **"user_pool_id"** value for CfnUserPoolClient from CfnUserPool resource?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the reference for others, the following will serve the purpose:

_user_pool_id = _cognito_user_pool.ref

Answer (score 0):

Answer - I have resolved this issue by using UserPool instead of CfnUserPool. UserPool has "user_pool_id" attribute and we can fetch it's id value using this attribute.